# PHP negative value after substraction (floating point error?)

Tags: php, math, precision

I have the following problem: when calculating the cost for delivery of an order, I noticed that in some cases (`-1.4210854715202E-14` in my case) a floating point error shows up. You can find the function I am using below, the error shows up when `$orderTotal` has the same value as `$totalPackagePrice`.

```
public function getPaidPackages()
{
    $orderTotal = doubleval($this->total_price); //price the customer paid for
    $totalPackagePrice = doubleval($this->getTotalOrderPrice()); //price of all the orderitems within all the packages combined

    //error shows up when substracting the same values (e.g. 68.55 in my case)
    $packagingCosts = $orderTotal - $totalPackagePrice; //shows a negative value when debugging

    ...
}
```

Any help to tackle this problem is appreciated, so far I've tried to cast both input values to a `float` or a `double` to no avail.

Comment: It might be useful to see that numbers that are being used in this calculation when the issue occurs

Comment: `-1.4210854715202E-14` is basically `0`. Just because a quantity is mathematically `0`, it doesn't imply that your float calculations will result in `0` exactly. That isn't how floats work.

Comment: Try `money_format` or `number_format` on the result and you should be fine, eventually can also see the `bcsub`.